# Using ArcGIS Pro to select all data collected "Yesterday" regardless of the time of day

Tags: sql, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, date, datetime

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.3.
I can upgrade if needed.

I am reading a hosted feature layer from my Organisation's AGOL site in ArcGIS Pro.  This is using the standard Esri Data Store.  This dataset has a date field "CreatedOn" in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

I want to use the "Select Layer by Attribute" tool to select all records that were captured yesterday.

I need the selection to be "yesterday" rather than a specific date as I want to use the tool in a model in ModelBuilder that will run daily, hence I need this to be a dynamic selection.

I have so far tried the following:

```
CreatedOn = CURRENT_DATE() -1
```

This returns all records collected yesterday at the exact time of day that I hit run on the query.

```
CreatedOn = CURRENT_TIME()- 1
```

This returns all records collected yesterday at the exact time of day that I hit run on the query.

```
CreatedOn = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()- 1
```

This returns all records collected yesterday at the exact time of day that I hit run on the query.

```
CreatedOn BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -1 AND CURRENT_DATE
```

This returns all records collected in the last 24 hours, not just yesterday. i.e.  If I run this query at 09:37 and a record was collected yesterday at 09:35, it won't return that record.  This will also return everything collected today.

```
CreatedOn BETWEEN CURRENT_TIME -1 AND CURRENT_TIME
```

This returns all records collected in the lat 24 hours, not just yesterday. i.e.  If I run this query at 09:37 and a record was collected yesterday at 09:35, it won't return that record.  This will also return everything collected today.

```
CreatedOn BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -1 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This returns all records collected in the lat 24 hours, not just yesterday. i.e.  If I run this query at 09:37 and a record was collected yesterday at 09:35, it won't return that record.  This will also return everything collected today.

```
CreatedOn BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -1 AND CURRENT_DATE -1
```

The expression is valid but won't return any records

```
CreatedOn BETWEEN CURRENT_TIME -1 AND CURRENT_TIME -1
```

The expression is valid but won't return any records

```
CreatedOn BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -1 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -1
```

The expression is valid but won't return any records

It seems that regardless of whether you use `CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_TIME` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` it always takes the time of day the record was collected into account and so either returns what was collected exactly 24 hours ago or what has been collected in the last 24 hours depending on the query.

Is there a way, without calculating an extra field, to truncate the date field on the fly within the query so that it always returns everything that was captured "Yesterday" regardless of the time?

Or is there a different tool I should be using in my model to do this?

My ultimate aim is to have a simple model that can be run once a day that will export all the features from the hosted feature layer (that were added the previous day) into a file Geodatabase.  Whether this is into an existing fGDB or a new fGDB every day doesn't really matter.

Comment: The date capabilities of the source come into play here, since Pro hands the WHERE clause to the format handler and date handling is as non-standard as is possible. Are you using file geodatabase or a real SQL engine (and if so, which one? Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: @Vince I have edited my post to make it clearer that the data is a hosted feature layer in an Organisational ArcGIS Online account.  This uses the standard Esri Data Store.

Comment: @BERA arcpy would also work.  The only reason I was using model builder is that I'm not a developer.  All I'm trying to do is create a copy into a fileGeodatabase of the features added Yesterday to a hosted feature layer.  Essentially creating a daily backup.  I will update the question now to make this clearer.

Comment: Data Store is PostgreSQL, so the `DATE_TRUNC` function should be available -- try `DATE_TRUNC('day',tstamp_col) = (CURRENT_DATE - 1)`.  If there's a lot of records, you can build a covering index on `DATE_TRUNC('day',tstamp_col)`.